# Globbing within a parameter expansion

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, wildcards

I'm trying to select the files within a set of directories passed as arguments with the following:

```bsh
${@/%/*}
```

However, this is not ideal, since paths with spaces will break, and quoting the parameter expansion will in turn stop filename expansion. Is a satisfactory solution possible?

P.S.: I'm aware you should use `find -maxdepth` to perform this, but I'm curious about why is mixing parameter expansion with globbing seemingly so hard.

Comment: How would `find -maxdepth` help here? (note that `-maxdepth` is not a standard `find` option)

Comment: `find -maxdepth 1` can return an equivalent list of paths as that of a wildcard, and also execute commands accordingly using `-exec`. I wonder what a POSIX solution would be like, but a parameter expansion like I proposed at first wouldn't be POSIX-compatible anyway.

Comment: Because globbing is more of a quick hack, not designed for any sort of heavy(er) lifting. There are plenty of non-shell tools for frobbing text (including file names, if so inclined) available.

Comment: Unless you meant `${@/%/\/*}` or the positional parameters always all end in `/`, I still don't see how `-maxdepth` would help here.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do:

```
IFS=              # don't split
files=(${@/%/*})  # use split+glob upon expansion with split disabled
```

However, if `"$@"` contains wildcard characters, they will be interpreted as such. Also, you'll end up with the patterns unexpanded for each of the globs that have no match.

You could address those with a loop and the `nullglob` option:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=()
for arg do files+=("$arg"*); done
```

Or you could use `zsh` instead of `bash` and use:

```
files=($^argv*(N))
```

`$^array` turns on the `rcexpandparam` option on for the one expansion of `$array`. In the `rc` shell (and that's also the case in the `fish` shell), `$array*` where `$array` contains two elements `a` and `b` expands as `a*`, `b*`, so here it's like doing `files=($argv[1]*(N) $argv[2]*(N)...)` (`$argv[1]` being the same as `$1`, only more verbose). `(N)` itself is a glob qualifier that turns on `nullglob` behaviour for that one glob.

In the `fish` shell, that would just be:

```
set files $argv*
```

as `fish` enables `nullglob`-like behaviour in arguments to `set` and expands arrays similarly to `rc`. But beware `fish` syntax is radically different from that of `bash` much more so than `zsh`.

Note that those are meant to expand the `"$1"*`, `"$2"*`... globs as your `${@/%/*}` would. If you actually meant `"$1"/*`, `"%2"/*`... globs, as your *files within a set of directories passed as arguments* suggests, you'd need  `${@/%/\/*}`, `"$arg"/*`, `$^argv/*(N)`, `$argv*` instead in the code pieces above.

Answer (score 0):

Replace other globbing characters by backslash+character. Either replace whitespace characters by backslash+character or (more robust) set `IFS` to an empty string. Remember to escape backslash first so that you don't end up re-escaping backslashes resulting from a previous escaping step. But don't escape anything if there's nothing to escape, because backslash is only special if there's a wildcard character.

Set the `nullglob` option to get an empty list, rather than an unexpanded pattern, if there is no match. Do this in a function and arrange to keep the changes to the shell options and to `IFS` local.

Minimally tested:

```
function set_patterns {
  typeset restore_shopt=$(shopt -p nullglob)
  shopt -s nullglob
  typeset IFS=
  typeset x
  patterns=()
  for x; do
    if [[ "$x" == *[*?[]* ]]; then
      x="${x//\\/\\\\}"
      x="${x//\*/\\*}"
      x="${x//\?/\\?}"
      x="${x//\[/\\[}"
    fi
    x="${x//%/*}"
    patterns+=($x)
  done
  eval "$restore_shopt"
}
```

Comment: Beware that escaping backslash for arguments that don't otherwise contain wildcards will behave differently in bash 5 from earlier versions (backslash became a wildcard characters in its own right in bash5)

Comment: Replacing whitespace character with backslash+character won't help at all here.

Comment: in bash5, backslash is special even if there's no wildcard character. `nl='\n'; printf %s $nl` will output `\n` if there's no file called `n` in the current directory (or an empty line with nullglob) and `n` otherwise.

Comment: You're making `patterns` local to the function. (and patterns end up being expanded in there), so the function produces no output.